# Possible misunderstanding regarding std::vector<T> object[arraySize]

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, copy-constructor

** This question is heavily edited to provide (after knowing the solution) an example of the problem in an MCVE format. The MCVE used to solve the problem can be found at [this ideone link](https://ideone.com/pzWCpU). **
(If ideone.com removes posts, someone let me know!)

Comments to this post include a link to a [rextester link](http://rextester.com/live/QQW10887) which has the edits provided by @dyp (although I don't know how that might change with time)**

```
template <typename T, size_t fD, size_t mD>
class Field
{
public:
    // Constructor - the problem turned out to be here
    Field(const Mesh<mD>& mesh, const std::string &fileName):
        fileName_(fileName),
        mesh_(mesh)
    {
        for (size_t d=0; d<fD; d++) {
            field_[d].reserve(mesh.numCellS());
        }
    }

    // Copy constructor - maybe I've written this horribly?
    Field(const Field<T,fD,mD>& refToCopy, const std::string &name):
        fileName_(name),
        mesh_(refToCopy.mesh_)
    {
        for (size_t d=0; d<fD; d++) {
            field_[d] = refToCopy.field_[d];
        }
    }

    // Const Accessors
    const std::vector<T> &x() const { return field_[0]; }
    // some checking that fD is large enough
    const std::vector<T> &y() const { return field_[1]; }
    // Repeated, non-const.

    void setZero();
    void setFixed(const T &val);

private:
    std::vector<T> field_[fD];
}

template<typename T, size_t fD, size_t mD>
void Field<T,fD,mD>::setZero()
{
    setFixed(T(0));
}

// This might need to be explicit.
// Currently, 'a' can be converted for Field<double, D>
template<typename T, size_t fD, size_t mD>
void Field<T,fD,mD>::setFixed(const T &val)
{
    for (size_t d=0; d<fD; d++) {
        std::fill(field_[d].begin(), field_[d].end(), val);
    }
}
```

When I try and access the values of a copied field (not one constructed from scratch), I get segfaults. Placing `std::cout << "field_[" << d << "][" << i << "] = " << field_[d][i]` inside a loop over `i` inside the copy-constructor also throws this problem (without any output, so presumably on the first value of `i`...

An example call might be:

```
Field<double, 2, 2> fieldA(constructor arguments);
fieldA.setZero(); // <- This is what I misunderstood
Field<double, 2, 2> fieldB(fieldA, "copyOfFieldA");
std::cout << "fieldB.x()[5] = " << fieldB.x()[5] << std::endl;
```

Where did I go wrong? Should I instead seek to use `std::array<std::vector<T>>`? Is this an invalid way to access a field? Or is my copy-constructor just junk (suspected case).

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/YFCTK56876). MCVE or it didn't happen.

Comment: I have no idea what kind of weird gcc extension allows this to compile: `field_(refToCopy.field_)` This is illegal; you can't copy an array via direct-initialization. clang++ complains about it. Since your copy ctor doesn't do anything special, why don't you just leave it out?

Comment: [This link](http://rextester.com/live/QQW10887) should compile and show error

Comment: @dyp - It compiles, but maybe it doesn't work? I don't think I've used it anywhere, so perhaps it's just never instantiated?

Comment: @chrisb2244 Well, yes, clang++ doesn't report any error/warning either if it is not instantiated. But it seems unrelated to your problem? The copy ctor in your rextester link and at the beginning of your answer looks more like the `Field(const Mesh<mD>& mesh, const std::string &fileName)` in your larger example.

Comment: @dyp assuming I didn't mess up the link, should give "Invalid memory reference". The field `Phi`, copied from `U`, should have valid values (all zero)

Comment: Ah, thanks, you've changed the link/code. I've hit http://rextester.com/YFCTK56876

Comment: @dyp - Yes, I think the copy constructor without string (i,e, the real copy constructor) is uninstantiated, and probably broken - I think I wrote it before changing the `field_` arrangement to an array. I'll delete/rewrite it, but I also agree that it isn't the problem this question is about - perhaps my title/comments in the short example made it unclear

Comment: I *think* the issue is that your `vectorField U` is in fact "empty"; in the sense that every array element of its `field_` is an empty vector. `vector::reserve` does not create any elements, it only changes the capacity (not the size) of a container. I don't see where any elements are inserted into those vectors. Use `vector::resize` instead of `vector::reserve` to change the size (number of elements) in a vector.

Comment: The `setZero()` -> `setFixed(T(0))` doesn't fill it?

Comment: Nice catch - running with your change shows filling size 0 vector... Guess I screwed that somewhere

Comment: It fills it, but there's nothing to fill. That is, it's filling all the 0 elements of the empty vectors. Insert something like `std::cout << "filling a vector of size: " << field_[d].size() << std::endl;` (not sure if you can see it live on rextester)

Comment: If you can see my changes live on rextester (never used it that way), I've replaced the `vector::reserve` with a `vector::resize` as suggested above.

Comment: Yup, looks like that was it. The constructor didn't create any elements, and so neither did the fill. If I wanted to stick with `reserve`, would I need to change the `setZero()`/`setFixed` calls to `push_back(..)`?

Comment: Well, you'd have to change those functions to generate new elements. E.g. by using `field_[d].assign(field_[d].capacity(), val);`, but using capacity here is **not** a good idea (because `reserve` reserves *at least* the passed capacity; it can reserve more than that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the comments, my understanding is that there were problems with the initialisation of the field (specifically the allocation + initialisation of vector elements in each dimension).

You can find the full running code [here](http://rextester.com/live/QQW10887).

**Problem 1**

Fixed-size arrays declared as `Type x[N]` cannot be copy-initialised using the syntax `x(y)`. Although note that [it works](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/array/) with `std::array`s.

**Problem 2**

`reserve` only affects the capacity of a standard container, not its size. In particular, using `std::fill` on a reserved but not resized container does nothing.

There is no workaround here other than iterating on each element of the fixed-sized array to resize (or [`assign`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/)) it manually.

---

In any case, I would recommend using C++11's `std::array`; there is no overhead, your code will be cleaner and you will be able to benefit more easily from move-operations.

Comment: @dyp Alright then, I guess you'll post a summary once you guys are through then? I'll just remove my answer :)

Comment: Actually, I don't have much time right now for an answer. Feel free to write one solving the issue the OP had (as described in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by @dyp. Posting since comments indicate he's busy.

The constructor uses `field_[d].reserve(mesh.numCells());`

This *reserves* memory for entries, but does not create any entries. (This I knew).

Subsequent calling of `fieldA.setZero()` calls `std::fill`, which *also* does not create entries (I'd missed this point)

When the copy is created, the program attempts to read values that don't exist, since although memory has been allocated, no value was ever placed there.

Consequently, the simplest solution is to change `field_[d].reserve(mesh.numCells());` to `field_[d].resize(mesh.numCells());` in the `Field` constructor.

Comment: See also my answer below, choose the one you like. :)